# Can't update to Subversion Edge 5.1, download stops at Downloading 0.00 KB (File 1078/1358)

Tags: subversion-edge

I have not been able to update to Subversion Edge 5.1 because everytime I start the upgrade process from with Subversion Edge it stops at the exact same place:

Downloading 0.00 KB (File 1078/1358)

It will just hang there forever. I have never had a problem updating before.

Does anyone have any insight of what I could look at to solve the issue?

**Update** Found this in the logs:

Exception in thread "Csvn Installer Daemon" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a forum post regarding this issue, there is a bug causing the divide by zero issue:

https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=563233

The solution is to do a manual upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1, instructions for that are here (going forward the software update in the app will work again):

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/ManualUpgrade

The forum post says they only saw this on Windows; however, I experienced the problem when running Subversion Edge on linux (Red Hat 6)